# BPM for Glassfish

Tags: jboss, glassfish, jbpm, business-process-management

Currently we're developing an enterprise app that requires JMS so we decided to get a JavaEE6 compliant app server which is Glassfish 3.1.2.2. We selected it over the rest because it's the reference implementation (JavaEE6) (I wonder if we've made the right choice?).

Now we're looking into a BPM technology that we can use/integrate with Glassfish, so far I only know JBPM with JBoss.

Any recommendation on BPM? And is Glassfish the correct choice or is JBoss the better one? Note that we can't afford Weblogic nor Websphere so both of them are out of the picture :-).

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having familiarity with JBPM4, obviously I was looking for something similar so I tried JBPM5, but it's obvious that it's an entirely different thing. And after reading some articles on google I've found out that JBPM5 is actually Drools. And JBPM4 successor is now with a different name "Activiti". So I go with Activiti. http://activiti.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you go ahead with jBPM5, there is no need to choose jBoss. You can use jBPM in any Application Server so you don't need to be afraid of the Application Server that you choose. You can consider jBPM as hibernate, a completely independent framework to add the BPM capabilities to your application.

Cheers

Comment: I have the same thought, but my concern is I found few tutorials, document on how to use jBPM5 with Glassfish3.x. Ok will try to work that out. Thanks :-).

Comment: Try it out at let us know if you have troubles. Jbpm5 is agnostic to the environment where it is deployed.

Comment: Well to my surprised it worked almost out of the box. I just added a jbpm5 dependency to my project import the bpmn file and started a knowledgebase :-) I'll write more about it later and share it here.

Comment: Keep me posted about your progress, we can write a blog post for the official jbpm/drools blogs. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We spent much time to get jBPM running in Glassfish, without success! The problems are starting with a persistent process store. kie-server.war ist not deployable on Glassfish, the same with jbpm-console.

Till today developing a Java EE application does not mean, that its deployable on all application servers, unfortunately.